# WinSCP to google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have google cloud compute engine instance. I'm trying to connect using winSCP. I followed the steps by https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

It is stating "Connection Timed out error" What should be the cause. Should I need to open firewall in google cloud? But it doesn't shown in the instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should have a GCE firewall rule added for SSH protocol to allow this traffic to the VM instances that you want to connect. This is a quote from this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewall_rules):

> Each network has its own firewall controlling access to the instances.
>
> All traffic to instances, even from other instances, is blocked by the
>   firewall unless firewall rules are created to allow it.
>
> The default network has automatically created firewall rules, which
>   are shown below. No manually created network of any type has
>   automatically created firewall rules. For all networks except the
>   default network, you must create any firewall rules you need.
>
> Firewall rules are only "allow" rules. You cannot create "deny" rules.
>   If you need to restrict traffic from reaching certain instances,
>   create rules that allow traffic to the other instances, then remove
>   the firewall rule that allowed traffic to all of the instances.
>
> The firewall rules automatically created for the default network are
>   as follows:
>
> **default-allow-internal**
>
> Allows network connections of any protocol and
>   port between instances on the network.
>
> **default-allow-ssh**
>
> Allows SSH connections from any source to any instance on the network over > TCP port 22.
>
> **default-allow-rdp**
>
> Allows RDP connections from any source to any instance on the network over > TCP port 3389.
>
> **default-allow-icmp**
>
> Allows ICMP traffic from any source to any instance on the network.